# Getstream- How to filter fake likes?

Tags: getstream-io

I have the user feed.If the user posts the activity, the same follower like two times,the likes count increased.how to avoid that?

when i post the activity, the followers can like the activity multiple times

Answer (score 0):

The best way to avoid that is to not send duplicate reactions to Stream. The [React library](https://getstream.io/react-activity-feed/) already enforces this. While we do not enforce uniqueness for reaction kinds, support for this will be added soon.